# C++ Days Passed in the Year

Tags: c++

Hello i been doing some program , my program is to get the number of days passed in the year. Now when i try to run and the output gives me "4438232".

For example if the user enter (mm-dd-yy) 3-18-2013, then the reaming days passed in the year is 77.

Does this code make sense on getting the reaming days passed in the year?

```
void dateType::Num_DayPassed()
{
     int sum;
     int yy = 365;
     if (month ==1)
        {
            cout<<"Number of days Passed in the Year: "<<sum<<endl;
            day=31;
            sum=day-yy;
        }
  ........
 continued until month 12..
```

[Full Code](http://ideone.com/Z3pSbW)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ejHn.jpg)

Comment: You already have a good answer, so I'll just add the important point that date/time calculations are notoriously tricky. Doing your own is okay for learning programming, but with dates especially, I would use a proven library if this will ever be used by someone.

Comment: still confuse what is he trying to say :( [Here the new code] (http://imgur.com/a/PRnhP) i get -334

Comment: we're not going to click on your external links, sorry

Comment: i exchange sum=day-yy to sum=yy-day it gives me remaining days in the year which i also need.. now the passed day is the problem

Answer (score 2):

C++ programs run top-to-bottom.  You're outputting `sum` before you set it.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also use this logic:
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class dateType
{
private:
int dMonth; 
int dDay; 
int dYear; 
void setDate(int month, int day, int year);
void set_Date();
void setNew_Date();
void add_days(int D);
int return_day(int M);
bool check_leap(int y);
int pass_days();
int remaining_days();
int getDay() const;
int getMonth() const;
int getYear() const;
void printDate() const;
void set_month(int m);
void set_day(int d);
void set_year(int y);
public:
dateType(int month = 1, int day = 1, int year = 1900);
void choice();
};
void dateType::set_Date()
{
    cout<<"Enter Date in (dd/mm/yy) formate:"<<endl;
    int d,m,y;
    cin>>d>>m>>y;
    setDate(m,d,y);
}
dateType::dateType(int month , int day , int year)
{
    setDate(month,day,year);
}
void dateType::setDate(int month, int day, int year)
{
    set_day(day);
    set_month(month);
    set_year(year);
   
}
void dateType::printDate() const
{
   cout<<dDay<<"\\"<<dMonth<<"\\"<<dYear<<endl;
}
int dateType::return_day(int M)
{
    for(int i=1;i<13;i++)
    {
        if(i==M && M==2)
        {
            return 28;
        }
        else if(i==M && (M==1||M==3||M==5||M==7||M==8||M==10||M==12))
        {
            return 31;
        }
        else
        return 30;
    }
}
bool dateType::check_leap(int y)
{
     if((y%400 == 0 || y % 100 !=0 )&& y%4==0)
       {
        return true;
       }
     else
      return false;
}
void dateType::setNew_Date()
{
    set_Date();
}
void dateType::add_days(int D)
{
       if(dMonth==2)
       {
          dDay=dDay+D;
          if(dDay>28)
            {
                dMonth++;
                dDay=dDay-28;
            }
       }
       else if(dMonth==1||dMonth==3||dMonth==5||dMonth==7||dMonth==8||dMonth==10||dMonth==12)
       {
          dDay=dDay+D;
          if(dDay>31)
          {
            dMonth++;
            dDay=dDay-31;
          }
          else if(dDay>31&&dMonth==12)
          {
            dYear++;
            dMonth=1;
            dDay=dDay-31;
          }
       }
       else
       {
        dDay=dDay+D;
        if(dDay>30)
        {
            dMonth++;
            dDay=dDay-30;
        }
       }
}
int dateType::pass_days()
{   
    int count=0;
      for (int  i = 1; i <dMonth; i++)
      {
           if(i==2)
          {
              for(int i=1;i<=28;i++)
              {
                count++;
                 if(check_leap(2))
                 {
                    count++;
                 }
              }
          }
       else if(i==1||i==3||i==5||i==7||i==8||i==10||i==12)
       {
         for(int i=1;i<=31;i++)
              {
                count++;
              }
        }
       
       else
       {
        for(int i=1;i<=30;i++)
              {
                count++;
              }
      
       }  
      }
      return count+dDay;
}
int dateType::remaining_days()
{

    if(dMonth!=2)
    return 365-pass_days();
    else
    return 366-pass_days();
}
void dateType:: set_day(int d)
{
   if(d<31)
    {
        dDay=d;
    }
    else
    dDay=1;
}
void dateType::set_month(int m)
{
    if(m<=12)
    {
        dMonth=m;
    }
    else
    dMonth=1;
}
void dateType::set_year(int y)
{
    dYear=y;
}
void dateType:: choice()
{
    set_Date();
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"1.Update Date"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Check leap year"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Find number of days remaining:"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.Find number of days passed:"<<endl;
        cout<<"5.Find number of days of a month"<<endl;
        cout<<"6.Add Days to Date"<<endl;
        cout<<"7.Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
        int choice;
        cin>>choice;
        if(choice==1)
        {
            cout<<"1.Update Month"<<endl;
            cout<<"2.Update Year"<<endl;
            cout<<"3.Update Day"<<endl;
            cout<<"4.Exit"<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
            int choice1;
            cin>>choice1;
            if(choice1==1)
            {
                cout<<"Enter the month: ";
                int month;
                cin>>month;
                set_month(month);

            }
            else if(choice1==2)
            {
                cout<<"Enter the year: ";
                int year;
                cin>>year;
                set_year(year);
            }
            else if(choice1==3)
            {
                cout<<"Enter the day: ";
                int day;
                cin>>day;
                set_day(day);

            }
            else
            break;
           cout<<"Updated Dated:  ";
            printDate();
        }
        else if(choice==2)
        {
          if(check_leap(dYear))
          {
            cout<<"It is a leap year"<<endl;
          }
          else
          {
            cout<<"It is not a leap year"<<endl;
          }
        }
        else if(choice==3)
        {
            int rem=remaining_days();
            cout<<"Remaining days: "<<rem<<endl;
        }
        else if(choice==4)
        {
            int pass=pass_days();
            cout<<"Passed days: "<<pass<<endl;
        }
        else if(choice==5)
        {
            int days=return_day(dMonth);
            cout<<"Days in month  "<<dMonth<<" : "<<days<<endl;
        }
        else if(choice==6)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Number of Days you want to add  to the Date"<<endl;
            int days;
            cin>>days;
            add_days(days);
            cout<<"Updated Dated:  ";
            printDate();
        }
        else
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    dateType D;
     D.choice();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
   void dateType::Num_DayPassed()
        {
            int sum;
            int yy = 365;
 
             if (month ==1)
            {
                cout<<"Number of days Passed in the Year: "<<sum<<endl;
                day=31;
                sum=day-yy;
            }
            else if (month==2)
            {
                cout<<"Number of days Passed in the Year: "<<sum<<endl;
                day=60;
                sum=day-yy;
            ...
```

Gets kind of long quickly. Rather than hardcode 12 cases statements in a single function (one for every month), your a lookup table for the days in the month and simple loop to count up.

Here's much simplified version of what you are after. I'll let you decide how to integrate it with your `dateType` class.

```
bool isLeapYear(int year)
{
   if (year % 4 != 0) return false;
   if (year % 400 == 0) return true;
   if (year % 100 == 0) return false;
   return true;
}

// returns the number of days that have passed before month/day/year
int getDaysPassedInYear(int month, int day, int year)
{
    int days_in_month[] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    days_in_month[2] = isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
    
    // sanity check params
    if ((month > 12) || (month < 1) || (day < 1) || (day > days_in_month[month]) || (year < 1))
    {
        return -1; // error - bad parameter
    }

    // now count the days
    int days_passed = 0; // initialize to "1" if you want to include the target date into the number of days passed

    // start on january 1
    int m = 1;
    int d = 1;
    
    // now count the number of days that need to elapse
    // until the intended month/day date
    while (m != month && d != day)
    {
        days_passed++;
        d++;
        if (d > days_in_month[m])
        {
            m++;
            d = 1;
        }
    }
    return days_passed;
}
```